# Arranging by number of characters in variable

Tags: r

I would like to arrange a variable called "Name" by the number of characters in their Name. I'm aware that I need the `arrange()` function in the package `dplyr`, but do not find a function in the `arrange()` function that helps me to arrange based on numbers of characters in the name.

So far I have come up with: `arrange((Name))`

Is there someone who can help me with this?

Comment: Just use `nchar()` to count the characters and then `arrange` on that, i.e. something like `arrange(nchar(Name))`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It did work. But now I want to arrange the Name variable in the same way in a barplot using the ggplot package. x = name, but this variable needs also be arranged based on number of characters in the name. Do you know how this works?

Comment: That is a whole different question.

Comment: I know, the original question was the first step. Can you help me with that question?

Comment: You need to open a new question and ask about ploting it. However, please have in mind the following: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I reached my question limit (of 1 question per day), so I can not open a new question to ask about the arrange problem in a barplot. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple workaround with `dplyr` package and `iris` data:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species)) %>% # Convert factor to characters
  arrange(nchar(Species))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It did work. But now I want to arrange the Name variable in the same way in a barplot using the ggplot package. x = name, but this variable needs also be arranged based on number of characters in the name. Do you know how this works?